# Display List of subcategories and links in WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to display the subcategorise for X category page.

and i'm using this code:

```
    <?php
    if (is_category()) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=true&orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
    if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>')
    {
    echo '<h3>Products</h3>'; 
    echo '<ul>'.$this_category.'</ul>'; 
    }
    }
    ?>
```

but is not showing good and not showing the post link under the selected category .

I want to display this list with button for each one.

Comment: I found another code but i still can't display the LInks and to display the category as a button 

  <?php wp_list_categories('child_of='.$cat); ?>